# Can we earn badges by sharing a link somewhere other than Twitter and Facebook?

Tags: support, badges

As far as I understand from [the related page](https://askubuntu.com/badges), at the moment we can share a guestion on Twitter and Facebook and seems that there's a possibility to earn announcer, booster and publicist badges for some defined traffic from there. I use neither Twitter nor Facebook. I have some other places to share links of some questions. For sure I can and shall do it, by simply announcing the plain url of the question, for the sake of spreading the word and not for earning badges. On the other hand, given the condition that we are playing such a "game", it won't be bad to earn badges at all. Is there a way to do it? If not, is it hard or useless to have such a feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy from the "link" button below the question.  Sharing is tracked by your user ID:

> http://askubuntu.com/q/[question-id]/[user-id]

Share this any way you like!

You can also drop the user ID to get a semi-short URL; you can even use an [answer ID](https://askubuntu.com/q/2527).

Comment: I'm sharing such a link on google plus, but I'm not earning the badge.