# Twitter question intro too long and wordy

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I want to start tweeting the good questions and answers, when I did one the tweet text came out like this:

> Stack Exchange Ubuntu Q: Unity crashes when I move the cursor over it. http://t.co/AnkE8RL

I think this is too wordy and it doesn't emphasize the question until the middle of the tweet, it also doesn't use the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

> Unity crashes when I move the cursor over it - askubuntu.com http://t.co/AnkE8RL

or

> askubuntu.com - Unity crashes when I move the cursor over it - http://t.co/AnkE8RL

Answer (score 1):

> Unity crashes when I move the cursor over it. https://askubuntu.com/q/10568/235
>   
> Unity crashes when I move the cu... https://askubuntu.com/q/10568/235

The ellipsis is only needed for longer titles, but I included it here to show what that would look like.  Using a ["SE short link"](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/562/can-we-earn-badges-by-sharing-a-link-somewhere-other-than-twitter-and-facebook/563#563) automatically includes the domain name and saves 7 characters over "t.co" (4+" - ") in [your suggestion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/645/twitter-question-intro-too-long-and-wordy/646#646), giving room for "q/" and the user ID.

It does look a little weird without any punctuation at the end of the title before the URL (in the first example above), but many question titles end with a question mark.  Including a hyphen if they don't end in punctuation would be my preference.  And I see now that the original title did include a period, so adding that to the above example.

Comment: Why is the URL so long? What does the `/235` add?

Comment: @Oli: That's the user ID for the publicity badges (announcer, booster, publicist), which is the encouragement used to share links.  If you try to share a link on Twitter, you'll see it's included in what is turned into the t.co short link.